Node.js Fetch Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
I'm encountering a DNS resolution error when trying to fetch data from Unsplash using Node.js. Here are the details of my setup and the error message I'm seeing:

const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const url = 'https://www.unsplash.com/photos/a-single-white-daisy-on-a-yellow-background-Cp3hn6MkNgw';

fetch(url)
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Network response was not ok ${response.statusText}`);
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(err => console.error('Fetch error:', err));

and this was the error message that i got

Fetch error: request to https://www.unsplash.com/photos/a-single-white-daisy-on-a-yellow-background-Cp3hn6MkNgw failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND www.unsplash.com
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hp\Documents/pathtofile)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:519:28)
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListner (node:_http_client:500:9)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:519:28)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/stream/destroy:169:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  type: ‘system’,
  code: ‘ENOTFOUND’
}


Troubleshooting Steps Taken:
Verified internet connectivity.
Checked DNS settings (using Google's DNS: 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4).
Flushed DNS cache (ipconfig /flushdns).
Restarted network adapter.
Restarted the computer.
Checked for proxy settings (none configured) and VPN (disabled).
Tried resolving DNS using nslookup which failed

Can you provide the output of nslookup? If that already fails for unsplash.com, it will lead us closer to the issue.
